# Test mode for Ads API

Tags: facebook, ads

I want to know - is it possible to add advertising on facebook in test mode? Functions "adcampaign" goes well, but "adgroup"  requires a balance . Is this necessary?

Comment: My recommendation here would be to create all your campaigns as paused, or with bids of 0.01, and cancel or delete them once you're finished with the testing

Answer (score 2):

> **Testing the Ads API**
>
> Once Facebook has whitelisted your application, you can test the API
>   calls using the Graph API Explorer tool. The Graph API Explorer
>   enables you to test almost any query you would like to make to the Ads
>   API; read the blog post for all the functionality provided. Please be
>   sure to select your whitelisted application from the "Application"
>   drop down as well as the ads_management permission in the pop-up
>   dialog (under extended permissions) when generating your access token.
>
> The API is live, so Facebook does not provide a sandbox where you can
>   test your code.

For more information see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/

Answer (score 0):

If your app is not whitelisted yet, you can always use similar APIs from simpleapi.launchrock.com
I think there is a sandbox version also.